# Returning a function with pre-assigned constants in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to make a function returning a function.

```js
const f = (value) => {
  return (input) => (value <= input);
};
```

expected:

```js
f(3).toString();
// "(input) => (3 <= input);"

eval(f(3).toString())(4);
// true
```

actual:

```js
f(3).toString();
// "(input) => (value <= input);"

eval(f(3).toString())(4);
// Error: input is undefined
```

Can I generate a function with pre-assigned dynamic constants?

---

I am making a kind of code generator. I try to convert the function to string and save to 'some.js'. My goal is that the users of 'some.js' don't have to know about arguments of `f`, when they use it.

Comment: Why `toString`/`eval`? Why not just `f(3)(4)`?

Comment: @melpomene I am making a kind of code generator. I try to save the function code returned by `f(3)` to 'some.js'. My goal is that the users of 'some.js' don't have to know about arguments of `f`, when they use it.

Comment: If you need 3 to be a literal part of the string, then have `f` return a string. `f = (val) => '(input) => (' + val + ' <= input);'`

Comment: @NicholasTower Yes. I can just `\`return (input) => (${value} <= input);\``. But it is not scalable. I want to generate a string from a real function code.

Comment: If you want to generate a string from a real function, then it will have the text of that function. Lexical information will not be contained in the string. You seem to have mutually exclusive requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `f(3).toString()` you can store `f.toString() + '(3)'`:

```js
f = value => input => value <= input

s = `(${f})(${3})`
console.log(s)
console.log(eval(s))

console.log(f(3)(4))
console.log(eval(s)(4))
```

Answer (score 0):

The process of "pre-assigning constants" is called [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application).

You can do this yourself using Function's prototype method [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), e.g.:

```
const add = (x, y) => x + y
const add3 = add.bind(null, 3)
add3(4) // === 7
```

You can also use useful 3rd party libraries like [lodash's `partial`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#partial) or [`partialRight`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#partialRight) method.

The reason your above example did not work, is because `f(3)` returns a function. Calling `toString` will give you a string representation of the body of that function.

When you invoke the result of `f(3)`, it will `eval` the string, but with a closure in which `value` is defined and has the value of `3`. Since you are calling `eval` on the string, it is looking for a named variable called `value` in your global scope.

If you do not know what I am referring to, I recommend you read up on [javascript closures](https://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#function.closures), there's a lot of resources on the subject.

I hope this was a step in the right direction, write a comment if something's not clear :)

Answer (score -1):

Other than using eval, you're pretty much there.

```
const f = (value) => {
  return (input) => (value <= input);
};

const isGreaterThanOrEqualTo3 = f(3);

console.log(isGreaterThanOrEqualTo3(4)); // logs out true
console.log(isGreaterThanOrEqualTo3(2)); // logs out false
```